Bulk Update a field in Dataverse table
I have a dataverse table having a datetime field . Now I have existing data in the field around 50k records. Now I need to make update to all the rows of that field, which is basically I need to adjust the time and subtract 4 hours from the existing date time data for all the rows.
Is there a way I can acheive that in dataverse, using some bulk update or anything like that?

To perform a bulk update on a Dataverse table where you need to adjust the datetime field by subtracting 4 hours from the existing data in all rows (around 50,000 records), using a Dataflow is a more suitable option than Power Automate. Here's why:

Efficiency: Dataflows handle large data volumes more efficiently than Power Automate, which may struggle with high record counts.
Performance: Optimized for bulk operations, Dataflows perform large-scale data manipulations quickly.
Integration: Dataflows integrate seamlessly with Dataverse

In contrast, using Power Automate for the same task would:

Take a very long time to process
Require implementing paging, as the "for-each" loop is limited to 5,000 records per batch.

More information about dataflow here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/dataflows/overview-dataflows-across-power-platform-dynamics-365

answers generated with AI are not allowed on stackoverflow  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned

@GuidoPreite, this answer is a little strange for a stackoverflow answer about Dataverse table update (Suggesting more complex Dataflow to person who is confortable with low-code PowerAutomate), plus ChatGPT will suggest a similar answer to this question, but other then that, how do you know it's AI generated?

@siggi_pop the style of the answer, plus there are tools where you paste the text and it tells you if is AI generated or not (of course they are not perfect but they give you a good indication)

and also the fact that the answer is not correct. To do achieve this bulk pudate, you would use XRM Toolbox (e.g., tool called SQL4CDS to perform a set on the table). Also, you DO can use bulk operations with Power Automate.


Make sure the Datetime is in fact incorrect

Dataverse uses UTC time to store DateTime, but the datetime is presented in UI to user in relation to the user's local timezone which you have to take into account.

PowerAutomate is a slow and inefficient way to bulk update a table

Since you are comfortable using PowerAutomate you probably are used to working with Data import from Excel sheet or csv source (at least it is easy).
Importing Data using the import wizards, can handle a large set of data, and it's easy process. You import the Excel file and wait... (takes a few minutes) that's all you have to do.
The process should be fairly simple: Export data, Modify data, import Data

In PowerPlatform, create a personal view with filter that shows all the records you want to update.
In the new personal view, modify columns view to only show the datetime field you want to update (this is for efficiancy when importing)
Export the view as .xlsx (excel file)
Modify data: Open the Excel file, create a new temporary column next to the datetime column (asumming it starts from D2), in the new column and in cell e2 create a formula =D2-TIME(4, 0, 0). Drage/copy the formula down to the end of datetime column aprox row number 50k (asumming you know how to copy formulas)
Replace Datatime: You should have now have column D with the old datetime and Column E with the new Datatime (old date minus 4 hours). Select Data in column E, and copy/paste over Column D (important: paste only as value)
Cleanup: Delete the temporary column E: (delete entire column, since it will not be used). Now your workbook sheet only contains column D with the modified datetime. Save file.
In Power platform, open the table view, select import, select your file, Import.

That should be it.
